# convert numpy array with 2d to numpy array with 1d

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

Good day, I am trying to run a regression analysis by calling numpy.polyfit(), but I got a 1D dimension error on x variables which happens to have 13columns and 506 rows.
I  was able to convert x variables from the dataframe to numpy array, but the shape is still in 2D. Before  I can be able to run polyfit on the dataset,x variables need to be in 1D shape. I have checked similar questions but none seems to provide an answer to my question.

below are my codes:

```
import numpy


y=house.iloc[:,-1]

#x=house.iloc[:,1:13]

#x=x.to_numpy()

numpy.polyfit(x,y,deg=1)
```

Below is the shape for x variables

x.shape

(506, 12)

Below is the error message:

```
551         raise ValueError("expected deg >= 0")

552     if x.ndim != 1:
```

--> 553         raise TypeError("expected 1D vector for x")

```
554     if x.size == 0:

555         raise TypeError("expected non-empty vector for x")
```

TypeError: expected 1D vector for x

And when I tried to reshape, I got an array in the following format:

array([[ 65.2  , 396.9  ,   0.   , ...,  15.3  ,   1.   ,   6.575],

```
   [ 78.9  , 396.9  ,   0.   , ...,  17.8  ,   2.   ,   6.421],

   [ 45.8  , 394.63 ,   0.   , ...,  18.7  ,   3.   ,   6.998],

   [ 89.3  , 393.45 ,   0.   , ...,  21.   ,   1.   ,   6.794]])
```

I want it to be such that when I call x. shape, I should get (12), that is the columns will become rows.
Any useful solution will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: With `house.iloc[:,1:13]` you are selecting all rows and 12 columns, hence the (506,12) shape.  For `polyfit` (read the docs), the first variable should have shape (m,), and the second (m,) or (m,n).  The first is the 'independent variable', it can only be one series of values, not 12.  What exactly are you trying to fit?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, well  I expected to get a series of values with 12 rows. So my question is how do I transform 12columns and 506rows to 12rows? because polyfit only expects my the first variable(x) to be in series, also not that in the actual data there are 12 columns and 506 rows,but because I intend using polyfit I want it transformed.polyfit is used to fit a regression model.

Comment: Fit tries to model `y = f(x)`.  `x` is the first variable, (506,) values, the independent variable in the problem.  `y` can be (506,12) if you want 12 sets of fitting parameters, one set per 'column'.  You haven't explained what you are trying to model or fit.

Comment: well from my understanding x is not just 506,x is the number of features(independent variables) that has 506 rows. and y is just a vector which is the target variable, you asked what am trying to fit? well, am trying to fit a regression model. I don't have a problem with y, I only have a problem with x.

Comment: Then why are you using `polyfit`?  Who or what told you to use this?

Comment: Well, I decided to use polyfit because when I tried to fit my model with simple linear regression(Statsmodel), the value of my R^2 and adjusted R^2 was too small meaning the model will not be able to predict well and in polyfit, there is a parameter called deg where I choose to increase the degree of polynomial.Maybe having a higher degree of polynomial will get me a better result